# Python-polars: expanding window groupby

Tags: python, python-polars

I'd like to calculate aggregated metrics with an expanding window. Basically, given the following dataframe:

```py
from datetime import date
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({"Day":[date(2022, 1, i) for i in range(1,10)], "value":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
shape: (9, 2)
┌────────────┬───────┐
│ Day        ┆ value │
│ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ date       ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-02 ┆ 2     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-03 ┆ 3     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-04 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...        ┆ ...   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-06 ┆ 6     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-07 ┆ 7     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-08 ┆ 8     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-09 ┆ 9     │
└────────────┴───────┘
```

What I'm after is basically this:

```
|--|
|-----|
|--------|
```

I tried to use `groupby_rolling` and `groupby_dynamic`, but I couldn't get it to fix the initial time of each group to the first timestamp. My current workaround is something like this:

```
date_range = pl.date_range(df.select("Day").min().row(0)[0], df.select("Day").max().row(0)[0], '1w',)
for timestamp in date_range:
    print(df.filter(pl.col('Day').is_between(date_range[0], timestamp, include_bounds=True)))
```

```
shape: (1, 2)
┌────────────┬───────┐
│ Day        ┆ value │
│ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ date       ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 1     │
└────────────┴───────┘
shape: (8, 2)
┌────────────┬───────┐
│ Day        ┆ value │
│ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ date       ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-02 ┆ 2     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-03 ┆ 3     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-04 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-05 ┆ 5     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-06 ┆ 6     │
...
│ 2022-01-07 ┆ 7     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-08 ┆ 8     │
└────────────┴───────┘
```

This gives me the exact aggregation I'm after, but I feel like there's a much more efficient way of doing this - and I'd especially like to do my aggregations within a groupby context.

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import date
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({"Day":[date(2022, 1, i) for i in range(1,10)], "value":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
shape: (9, 2)
┌────────────┬───────┐
│ Day        ┆ value │
│ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ date       ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╡
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-02 ┆ 2     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-03 ┆ 3     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-04 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...        ┆ ...   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-06 ┆ 6     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-07 ┆ 7     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-08 ┆ 8     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-09 ┆ 9     │
└────────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).